# Which of the following sentences are correct?

Tags: grammaticality, differences, prepositions, transitivity

Can someone please tell me which of the following sentences are correct and which are the differences between them?

> 1. Prove me wrong.
> 2. Prove I'm wrong.
> 3. Prove me I'm wrong.
> 4. Prove me that I'm wrong.
> 5. Prove to me I'm wrong.
> 6. Prove to me that I'm wrong.

Comment: 3. and 4. are incorrect.

Comment: What @Kyudos said. Other than that, there's no difference in meaning (another missing equivalent is *"Prove **that** I'm wrong"*).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments, 3 and 4 are incorrect.

*Prove me* is like saying *Smile me* - that doesn't make sense, you have to say *smile **at** me*.

Which leaves a problem with *1. Prove me wrong*. I'm afraid I can't explain why this is right, it just is. Maybe it's idiomatic, and we hear the missing words *Prove [to] me [I'm] wrong.*